# why is my django app not working on browser after running python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080

Tags: python, django

I'm running everything mentioned below in Vagrant.

I try to test my django app using the following command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Unfortunately, it seems running on my device, but is not accessible in chrome on `127.0.0.1:8080`. Here are the invocation logs:

```
(profile_api) vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/vagrant/src/profiles_project$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 08, 2023 - 14:43:56
Django version 1.11, using settings 'profiles_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.



127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

Comment: Are you sure 127.0.0.1 is the correct address?  Where did you get that number?

Comment: While running Django on vagrant, I forwarded the port to 127.0.0.1:8080.  And 0.0.0.0.8080 mean it is general.